# Paper size and printed magazine question

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design

I'm designing a magazine, and it's trim size is `272mm x 342mm` when printed. One of my other test InDesign files is `222mm x 291mm` at trim size (a fictitious local tourist guide).

What paper size would it be equivalent to - I know A4 is `210mm x 297mm`, but what would `222mm x 291mm` and `272mm x 342mm` be equivalent to as printed paper sizes?

I've looked up paper size converters on Google but couldn't find anything that would give an approximate answer, only the generic sizes of paper, for A4, A5, A3 etc. but not custom sizes.

(The magazine in question is not an actual project, this question is more general InDesign for educational-related since I'm learning this as a skill - not relating to a real work project)

Comment: Are you asking what format the _print house_ would use to print your 272x342? To account for the trim, stitching, folding etc?

Answer (score 1):

Not everything one creates has a "Standard" size.

Simply input the desired document dimensions in the "New" dialog box rather than looking for a standard preset size.

It should also be noted that some publications are purposefully reproduced at a slightly-less-than-standard-size in order to reduce cost of stock and allow bleeds on standard size sheets.